# How to remove borders of elevation effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design, elevation

Is it possible to remove the borders, which are part of the elevation, such that only the bottom part is visible? If so, how would you achieve this result?

I have already set the `Material`-widget property `borderOnForeground` to `false` without success.

```
Material(
  elevation: 5,
  child: SizedBox(width: 200, height: 200),
)
```

Highlighted borders should not exist.
[image]

Comment: what is this widget?

Comment: could you add the sample code that reproduce that issue?

Comment: that is not border. it is shadow. and that is how shadows work you can set it for just on side. but you can set border. do you want I tell you how to add border?

Comment: @eamirho3ein thank you for your answer. Is there any technique to remove those shadows?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `elevation` property to `0` you remove all those shadow, but can't remove only one side of them. One option you have is wrap your widget with `Container` and `birderSide` to it.

```
Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.black,
        width: 1.0,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Could you supply me with an example code?

Comment: I add the example.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I would love to stick to the shadow effect though. I'll upvote your answer anyways since it is also a valid solution.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't what you looking for.